# NFSACL GETACL / SETACL structes

Tags: c, acl, rpc, nfs, xdr

I have a proxy server between the client and server.

I use XDR to read and modify NFS messages between them

for example if i want to edit the file size for and get attributes reply
i use the struct and function

> GETATTR3res
>
> bool_t xdr_GETATTR3res ( XDR *xdrs, GETATTR3res *objp );

now i want to use the same method to modify replys for

> RPC:
>
> Program: NFSACL (100227)
>
> Program version: 3
>
> Procedure: GETACL (1) and SETACL (2)

i want to edit the (fattr3) attributes field with xdr

either a XDR function for NFSACL or even deconstructed XDR function for the fields NFSACL procedures have

Comment: Surely you can get this information more sensibly by running rpcgen on [`nfs_prot.x`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Librpcsvc/Librpcsvc-19.2/nfs_prot.x), which contains the RPC definitions themselves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found this list of structures that with smaller XDR function can be used to modify the attributes

```
struct GETACL3args {
    nfs_fh3 fh;
    uint32 mask;
};
typedef struct GETACL3args GETACL3args;

struct GETACL3resok {
    post_op_attr attr;
    vsecattr_t acl;
};
typedef struct GETACL3resok GETACL3resok;

struct GETACL3resfail {
    post_op_attr attr;
};
typedef struct GETACL3resfail GETACL3resfail;

struct GETACL3res {
    nfsstat3 status;
    union {
        GETACL3resok ok;
        GETACL3resfail fail;
    } res_u;
};
typedef struct GETACL3res GETACL3res;

struct SETACL3args {
    nfs_fh3 fh;
    vsecattr_t acl;
};
typedef struct SETACL3args SETACL3args;

struct SETACL3resok {
    post_op_attr attr;
};
typedef struct SETACL3resok SETACL3resok;

struct SETACL3resfail {
    post_op_attr attr;
};
typedef struct SETACL3resfail SETACL3resfail;

struct SETACL3res {
    nfsstat3 status;
    union {
        SETACL3resok ok;
        SETACL3resfail fail;
    } res_u;
};
typedef struct SETACL3res SETACL3res;
```

and using xdr_post_op_attr to decode and enconde back